# Laravel 5: Models, field names and localization

Tags: model, localization, field, laravel-5

I got a model with some fields, one field is, for example "postal_code", and the field is required.

I've also create a form. It the field is not filled, the validator creates an error message:

```
The postal code field is required.
```

If the locale is de, it will be:

```
postal code muss ausgefüllt sein.
```

Where can I define the translations for my field names of each model, and the validator getting to use them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute names can be translated as well as the error messages. This is done in the same `validation.php` language file with the `attributes` array:

```php
return [
    // ...
    'attributes' => [
        'postal_code' => 'Postleitzahl'
    ],
    // ...
];
```

Comment: Thank you, it works for the error messages, can I use the localizations for Form::label(), too? Form::label('postal_code')  returns the label text "Posta l Code", I don't like to have to write Form::label('postal_code',Lang::get('validation.attributes.postal_code'))

Comment: Not that doesn't work out of the box. You could write your own helper function though...